# Failed to load gived URL

Tags: html

i want to place images in my project web pages

i dont know how to point\path to the correct address of the image

i put the image in all of those folders but yet i dont see the image and
when i inspect it with fire bug i see that the browser failed to load the url.

```
 <img src="../calendar_schedule.png"> <img src="calendar_schedule.png">
<img src="admin/calendar_schedule.png">
```

only when i use this path i can see the image  - but it cant be the way

```
<img src="http://localhost:2734/Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png">
```

Comment: try <img src="admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png">, it really depends of the current path

Comment: Where to start?  `src="/....."` will get the image from the docroot of your web server if it's set correctly, `src="image.png"` gets it in the immeadiate folder.  If you're on Windows the case is likely to be insensitive.  On apache it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
<img src="Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png">
```

it will append to your url like this:

```
http://localhost:2734/ExamplePage1/Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png
```

You can use with first `/` to append directly to hostname

```
<img src="/Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png">
```

And it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:2734/Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to avoid using of server host part. You can do the next:

```
<img src="/Admin/Style/calendar_schedule.png">
```