# CSS display:none and :hover visibility

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to show an image when another image is hovered on. All works fine with Safari, but with Chrome and Firefox, the effect works and the image *placeholder* can be seen, but they fail to load the image. I have searched elsewhere and found topics to do with visibility:hidden etc, but none that deal with this issue cross-browser.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="profile-picture-wrap">
<a class="propic">
<img src="../images/propicsmall.jpg" width="142" height="194">
<span><img src="../images/profilepic.jpg" width="290" height="186" /></span></a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
    .propic span{
position:absolute;
padding: 5px;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
display: none;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
     }

    .profile-picture-wrap:hover .propic span{
display: block;
position:absolute;
top: -3px;
right: 900px;
left:  640px;

     }
```

Really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `z-index`?
Create a demo on [Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/), please.

Comment: Inspect the image using Firebug in Firefox. Then hover over the image source and see if it says "Failed to load URL". That would be a start...

Comment: Tooraj, someone beat me to it! See @Surendra's below. Going to try z index now.

Comment: @Rick, thanks for the comment, I'll check that, too.

Comment: @RickDonohoe, yep, 'failed to load URL'. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the images were .tiff files that had been renamed to .jpg. Chrome & Firefox don't seem to like this, and refused to recognise them as retrievable files.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your sample code ... and it appears to work fine in Chrome, after one small edit.

I had to change your paths from ../images/image.jpg to images/image.jpg

Have you used the developer tools in Chrome to see if the resource (image) was loading properly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried changing the path as you did, to no avail. Will check with the dev tools now.

Comment: Image has not loaded correctly.. First time I've come across this issue, thoughts?

Comment: Are you in a situation where you could user jquery?  or are you stuck with a restriction to use only css?  I also noticed that my trial although it worked in chrome, firefox and safari it fell down in ie.

Comment: did a litte more investigation check out this entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522503/failed-to-load-gived-url

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I am not. Thanks for pointing this out - I was aware of the lack of IE functionality, but I'm not really bothered about that one. I wonder why it's working for you, and not me?

Comment: I think the image was a .tiff screenshot I renamed as a .jpg - would this maybe be the problem?

Comment: Problem solved - the renamed .tiff can be recognised by Safari (presumably because it was created by it's brother, Grab, yet Chrome and Firefox do not recognise it as a loadable, valid filetype. Stupidly simple, thanks to everyone for the help - I'll know better for next time!

Answer (score 0):

I added z-index to .propic span css & change the left & right of span after hover to see it properly in jsfiddle window.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UH54X/1/

I am not sure that it will help you. I think you want like this only.

Comment: Thanks! I had put in a z index a while back, but it didn't work. However, many changes have been made since, I'll try it now, thanks :)

Comment: z-index did not work unfortunately. In Chrome, resource did not load for some reason..

Comment: I tested this fiddle on chrome & firefox & its working fine may be you are using older version. Is this fiddle working fine in your browser?

Comment: yeah the fiddle works fine in Chrome, safari and firefox, all updated to latest versions. Still cannot see image however. I added alt text to the image, which I can see, but upon inspecting the dev tools in firefox, it does not load the image. Not sure what to do.

Comment: may i know the folder structure? Is this html file is inside a folder?

Comment: Hey Surendra, yeah the html is inside a folder. Turns out the problem wasn't referencing the image, the problem was that firefox & chrome don't like .tiff files that have been renamed to .jpg, they won't recognise it as a retrievable file. Who knew.

Comment: Glad you found it. Add it as the question answer and accept it, that way it will help others who stumble upon the same issue!